# Need FineUploader Method uploadStoredFiles to Complete Before Proceeding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asynchronous, fine-uploader

For some quick background, uploadStoredFiles() is a method used in the FineUploader plugin to asynchronously send attached file data to a server path. I'm also using AngularJS for my application. My question is actually very similar to the one found here...

[jQuery: wait for function to complete to continue processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455870/jquery-wait-for-function-to-complete-to-continue-processing)

... the big difference is that I don't have access to the callback function itself. Also, my script is running FineUploader as part of a larger form where attachments are optional, so using a FineUploader 'completed' callback won't help much either.

Here's a code sample. Basically, if there are no attachments then the page should reload. If there are attachments, they should be uploaded, and THEN the page should reload.

```
if(hasAttachments)
{
    myuploader.uploadStoredFiles();
}

//AngularJS call to refresh page
$route.reload();
```

Most of the time, the page refreshes itself and the file is missing from its list until I do an additional refresh later on. I could hard code a wait time, but something about that seems inefficient and evil.

Any suggestions or solutions would be welcome. I would especially love an Angular-ish solution, but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: You’ll need a callback or promise from the method that sends data to the server in order to be able to "know" if the files has been uploaded or not.

Comment: Fine Uploader has events that run code when certain things happen such as when a file is submitted to the uploader (`onSubmit`) or when a file has uploaded (`onComplete`). Source: http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html

Comment: Seems just like this question, but with angular: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986202/jquery-form-submission-after-file-upload

Comment: [Here's an Angular example](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/11/01/full-stack-javascript-image-uploader-using-angularjs-node-js/) with Fine Uploader showing how to use the callbacks with Angular directives and such.

Comment: Mark, if you combined those three suggestions into an answer, it'd be a correct one. The link you provided was VERY close to what I needed, I just had to change it from a jQuery callback to the FineUploader version during initialization. Since it's Angular, I could use $scope & $route in the callback to handle my "hasAttachments" case. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I plan to type this into an answer when I find some time, I just wanted you to be able to get started asynchronously :P

Comment: You can use this angularjs module: [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) which is more angular way and it just put the files in your $scope and you can upload them right away or later. It is pretty simple, light-weight and super easy to set up. Check out the [Demo](angular-file-upload.appspot.com) page. It is cross-browser, support file progress/cancel, preview, multiple files and drag and drop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt at summarizing my comments into a cohesive answer:

Fine Uploader has events that run code when certain things happen such as when a file is submitted to the uploader (`onSubmit`) or when a file has uploaded (`onComplete`).

The vanilla JavaScript would look something like,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#triggerUpload").click(function () {
        $("#manual-fine-uploader").fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles'); 
    });

    function submitForm () { 
        if ($(this).fineUploader('getInProgress') == 0) {
            var failedUploads = $(this).fineUploader('getUploads', 
                { status: qq.status.UPLOAD_FAILED });
            if (failedUploads.length == 0) {    
                // do any other form processing here
                $("#uploader").submit();
            }
        }
    };

    // Instantiate a Fine Uploader instance:
    $("#manual-fine-uploader").fineUploader({
        autoUpload: false,
        request: {
            endpoint: "/uploads_bucket"
        }
    }).on("complete", function (event, id, name, response) {
        submitForm.call(this);
    }).on('statusChange', function (event, id, oldStatus, newStatus) {
        if (newStatus === qq.status.CANCELLED) {
            submitForm.call(this);
        } 
    });
});
```

You can use [this Angluar example](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/11/01/full-stack-javascript-image-uploader-using-angularjs-node-js/) as a starting point for making a Fine Uploader directive.